# WooCommerce checkout fields: using str_replace on a post meta field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, str-replace, checkout

I need to replace some character in my custom checkout field.

this is the whole code of my custom checkout field , (maybe we could use str_replace here)

```
/* Add the field to the checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">';

woocommerce_form_field( 'phone_sabet', array(
    'type'          => 'tel',
    'required'      => true,
    'clear'      => true,
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
    'label'         => __(''),
    'placeholder'   => __(''),
    'description'       => '',
    ), $checkout->get_value(('phone_sabet')));

echo '</div>';
}
```

---

this is the part of code when the custom field going to update

```
/* Update the order meta with field value */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta','my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( ! empty( $_POST['phone_sabet'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone_sabet'] ) );
}
}
```

i tired to use str_replace and change it to below but no luck.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( ! empty( $_POST['phone_sabet'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone_sabet'] ) );

    $getMeta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Phone', true);
    $newMeta = str_replace(array('۱'), '1', $getMeta);
    update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Phone', $newMeta);
}
}
```

---

and this is the part of when checkout field going to process.  its okay if we could done it with str_replace here.

```
/* Process the checkout */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
if ( $_POST['phone_sabet'] )
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct hook is **`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`**, so you could try this:

```
## Save the order meta with custom field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_update_order_meta' );
function custom_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['phone_sabet'] ) ) {
        // Replace before saving translating )
        $phone_sabet = str_replace( array('۱'), array('1'), $_POST['phone_sabet'] );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $phone_sabet ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

Comment: You can also use it on normal billing phone field, so you will target `$_POST['billing_phone']`, to make a replacement, but you will need to test the user phone data, and to save the value to the order meta data (the key is `'_billing_phone'`).